# Javascript/Node - Insertion of objects into array using for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need help regarding insertion of array elements as objects into another array in Javascript. I have the following code:

```
tableLength = 3;
nyCourt = [];
oldArr = [Buy, String, Question]

for (var t = 0; t < tableLength; t++) {
    nyCourt.push({});
        for (var i = 0; i < OldArr.length; i++) {
             nyCourt.Title = OldArr[i] ;
        }
};
```

The code isnt working, I want output in the following format

```
[{Title:Buy },
{Title: String},
{Title: Question}]
```

But the output I get is this:

```
[{Title:Question },
{Title: Question},
{Title: Question}]
```

Comment: *"But the output I get is this"* I don't think so, not with that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
nyCourt.Title = OldArr[i]
```

writes to the `Title` property on the `nyCourt` object (which is an array object), repeatedly in the loop. The last assignment wins.

But given what you've said you want your output to be, your code is over-complex. You only need one loop:

```
var nyCourt = [];
var oldArr = [Buy, String, Question];

for (var i = 0; i < oldArr.length; i++) {
    nyCourt.push({Title: oldArr[i] });
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/OKaQORO/1) (use Chrome or something else modern) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/OKaQORO/1/edit)

Or as this is Node so we know we have `map`:

```
var oldArr = [Buy, String, Question];
var nyCourt = oldArr.map(function(entry) {
    return {Title: entry};
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/OKaQORO/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/OKaQORO/2/edit)

Comment: @Rajat: That makes no sense, given the output you've said you want. **Why** do you want two loops?

Comment: Because that is an assignment :(

Comment: @Rajat: Due respect, I think you've misunderstood the assignment. You either need two loops and the result you're supposed to achieve isn't what you've listed, or the result you've listed is correct and you shouldn't use two loops.

Answer (score 1):

```
//this give the output you want
    tableLength = 3;
    nyCourt = [];
    oldArr = ['Buy', 'String', 'Question'];

    for (var t = 0; t < oldArr.length; t++) {
        nyCourt.push({Title: oldArr[t]});
    };

    console.log(nyCourt);
```

Answer (score 0):

place that push function inside the loop also change the code like this

```
for (var t = 0; t < tableLength; t++) {    
            for (var i = 0; i < OldArr.length; i++) {
                 nyCourt.push({"Title": oldArr[t]});
            }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks Arviin for the help